# DNS not working for specific websites

Tags: dns, home-networking

I'm trying to setup my first Wordpress site. For hosting, I have a [Combell](https://www.combell.com/en/) domain. At school I can access the domain. But when I am working from home, I can't reach the domain.

If I ping the domain, it says "Cannot resolve ... : Unknown host". If I ping the IP address, it is working.

I already tried flushing the DNS cache, but that didn't change anything.

Every device within my home network can't reach the domain. If I use the personal hotspot on my iPhone, it is working. So I'm guessing something's wrong with the DNS from my network.

I use the dynamic DNS from our internet provider.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic DNS from your ISP? What does your setup look like?

Comment: The dns adres is the adres I get when I connect to the network. So I mean not static as 8.8.8.8. My setup is a basic home-network setup. The router is protected by the ISP so I can't reach their DNS settings

Comment: What OS do you run, and what is the exact domain name?

Comment: The OS doesn't matter. I've tried mac and windows the domain name is 1819.jasper.vandevloet.nxtmediatech.eu